# Bayes Factor for linear mixed models in R

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-models, hierarchical-bayesian

I am trying to compute the Bayes Factor (BF) for one of the fixed effect with the `BayesFactor` package in R.

The data has the following structure:

- `rating` is the dependent variable
- `cond` is the independent variable with 3 levels (`"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"`)
- `C1` is a contrast code derived from `cond` that opposes `"A"` (coded `-0.50`) to `"B"` and `"C"` (both coded `-0.25`)
- `C2` is a contrast code derived from `cond` that opposes `"B"` (coded `-0.50`) to `"C"` (coded `+0.5`; and `"A"` is coded `0`)
- `judge` and `face` are random factors such that `face` is crossed with `judge` but nested within `cond` (and thus also nested within `C1` and `C2`)

```r
DT <- fread("http://matschmitz.github.io/dataLMM.csv")
DT[, judge := factor(judge)]
DT[, face  := factor(face)]

# > DT
#       judge face cond    C1  C2 rating
#    1:    66   13    A -0.50 0.0      1
#    2:    20   13    A -0.50 0.0      4
#    3:    22   13    A -0.50 0.0      7
#    4:    69   13    A -0.50 0.0      1
#    5:     7   13    A -0.50 0.0      3
#   ---                                 
# 4616:    45   62    C  0.25 0.5      2
# 4617:    30   62    C  0.25 0.5      6
# 4618:    18   62    C  0.25 0.5      4
# 4619:    40   62    C  0.25 0.5      3
# 4620:    65   62    C  0.25 0.5      1
```

Ideally I would like to test the "full" model as in:

```r
library(lmerTest)

lmer(rating ~ C1 + C2 + (1 + C1 + C2|judge) + (1|face), data = DT)
```

and compute the BF for `C1`.

---

I managed to compute the BF for `C1` but with random intercepts only:

```r
library(BayesFactor)

BF1 <- lmBF(rating ~ C1 + C2 + judge + face, whichRandom = c("judge", "face"), data = DT)
BF0 <- lmBF(rating ~ C2 + judge + face, whichRandom = c("judge", "face"), data = DT)
BF10 <- BF1 / BF0

# > BF10
# Bayes factor analysis
# --------------
# [1] C1 + C2 + judge + face : 0.4319222 ±15.49%
# 
# Against denominator:
#   rating ~ C2 + judge + face 
# ---
# Bayes factor type: BFlinearModel, JZS
```

I tried without success [this solution](https://forum.cogsci.nl/discussion/3749/random-slopes-in-lmbf) to include the random slopes:

```r
BF1 <- lmBF(rating ~ C1 + C2 + judge + face + C1:judge + C2:judge,
            whichRandom = c("judge", "face", "C1:judge", "C2:judge"), data = DT)
# Some NAs were removed from sampling results: 10000 in total.
```

I would also need to include (if possible) the correlation between the random intercepts and slopes for `judge`.

Please feel free to use any other package (e.g., `rstan`, `bridgesampling`) in your answer.

---

Some additional questions:

- Do I need to perform any transformation on the BF10, or can I interpret it as it?
- What are the default priors?

Comment: your last two questions are statistics questions and would be better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mike I totally agree. I'm leaving them there anyway if someone has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The covariate has to be a "factor".
In your case, not just the "judge", "face", "C1" and "C2" need to be a factor as well.

```
DT$C1 = factor(DT$C1)
```